# Symantec endpoint causing hang-ups

Tags: laptop, overheating, symantec

My Toshibea latptop overheats (gets up to 92 degrees Farenheit -- CORRECTION CELSIUS) whenever a Symantect full scan takes place.  suggestions?

---

Should I open up the back and try to clean the fan?

Whenever I hear the fan at maximum, and I feel a hot spot on the bottom of the laptop, I can find something in the task list that needs to be restarted -- except Symantec.  However, I've tried running an active or full scan manually, and I can reliably reproduce the symptom by starting a full scan, and I can reliably cool it off by aborting the full scan.

---

Correct, this Toshiba didn't used to have this problem.

Comment: It looks like Symantec Endpoint does *not* provide a setting by which you could limit CPU usage to a certain %. Shame. But you know what, 92F is nowhere near overheating. In fact, that's amazingly cool. You sure that's not 92**C** you're seeing?

Comment: Yup, 92F is not overheaing.. can you post a screenshot of Hwmonitor? http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html